# How to install image processing just for a virtualenv project with pip for django

Tags: django, pip

But I'm looking to install freetype, libjpeg, PIL build to add image processing to my django projects I've followed this installation http://dakrauth.com/blog/entry/python-and-django-setup-mac-os-x-leopard/ which installs it site wide but I can get it inside my virtualenv project.

Do I just cd into the working directory of the virtualenv (project) and install it there and will it just be available for that project or do I use pip? I couldn't find the packages in the pip repository. Can someone enlighten me please.

```
curl -O http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.21.tar.gz
tar -xzvf distribute-0.6.21.tar.gz
cd distribute-0.6.21
python distribute_setup.py
easy_install pip
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv --distribute --no-site-packages [myproject]
cd [myproject]
source bin/activate (this activates the sandbox that virtualenv created)
pip install django mysql-python
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the working directory of the virtualenv and then run

```
$ source bin/activate
```

This will set that virtual environment as your active one. So now that it's active, you can install what you want, either manually (by following those steps on the site you linked to) or with pip and it will automatically install it into your active virtualenv.

If you then, say, run `python manage.py runserver` while the same virtualenv is active, django will have access to your newly installed package. Once you want to unset that virtual environment as your active one, simply do `deactivate`.

Comment: After activating the virtual environment do I have to be inside the virtualenv folder to install them or can I be anywhere on the system like ~/?

Comment: You can be anywhere, as long as you have the virtual environment activated, that's what's cool about virtual environments.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar; what I did was install it into the default directory (e.g. Python27/Lib/site-packages) then cut and paste all the new files put there into the created environment's site-packages. Hacky, but works.

After that you can follow EEVIAC's instructions to actually get your server running.